# more command returns "Too many arguments in command line"

Tags: windows, command-line, more

I have a Windows 10 machine where running the `more` command returns *"Too many arguments in command line."* if I pass any filename, whether the file exists or not.

So far I've only seen this on one Windows 10 Home 64-bit x64 system.

Running `where more` returns `C:\Windows\System32\more.com` as I would expect.

Is this behavior of `more` expected? I've never encountered this on previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Certainly not expected.  ```more cowbell``` correctly displays the file ```cowbell``` on my Windows 10 Pro 64-bit system.

Comment: please include a paste from the command line showing this

Comment: According to ms docs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/more) you need to add `>` after `more` if you use it without flags, have you tried so?

Answer (score 5):

I just reproduced your problem on my own system. I definitely see what you're talking about... but I never noticed it before, because I always use `more` following a pipe (`|`), like this:

```
type filename.txt | more
```

That command works just fine on my system.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find this documented anywhere but I found a workaround. In this particular case `more` works as expected if extended features are enabled with the `/E` flag.

For example, the following will display `example.txt`:

```
more /E example.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce this, too, on Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1803, build 17134.407).  I can confirm Joel Coehoorn's and MrEricSir's solutions work.  FWIW, I liked the `/E` option because it made `more` behave more like the UNIX flavor.

My solution was to use input redirection:

```
more < cowbell.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `more` doesn't receive any input files without the `/E` option. Running `more /?` gives the below output:

```
MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]] < [drive:][path]filename
command-name | MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]]
MORE /E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n] [files]
```

So you'll have to use `more /E file`, `command | more` or `more < file` like what others said. See also 
https://ss64.com/nt/more.html

However sometimes running `more file` works, why? Look at the [documentation on MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/more) and you'll see that `more` can receive files directly

```
<Command> | more [/c] [/p] [/s] [/t<N>] [+<N>]
more [[/c] [/p] [/s] [/t<N>] [+<N>]] < [<Drive>:][<Path>]<FileName>
more [/c] [/p] [/s] [/t<N>] [+<N>] [<Files>]
```

There's not even a single mention of the `/E` option anymore. So it looks like the `more` was updated at some point and the help page wasn't updated accordingly